# Slide in and slideout using css3 and jquery without plugins

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I am using css3 animation to slide down a div to a list having few set of divs. I am trying to achieve  a slide in and slide out effect like vertical news ticker in this site

http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/totem/index.html

Css

```
.slidein { 
    animation: slide 1799ms linear; 
    top: 0px; 
    -webkit-animation: slide 1799ms linear;
}    
@keyframes slide {
    0% { top: -100px; }
    100% { top :0px; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    0% { top: -100px; }
    100% { top: 0px; }
}
```

I am prepending a div with the use of jquery adding the above class for slideIn effect

Jquery

```
 $(".parentDiv")
      .prepend('<div class="newdiv slidein"></div>')
      .children().slice(5);
```

Using slice to cut down all the other divs in the paent div.

For Slide down i tried to use the follwing div to move it up and down using top and bottom values

```
$(".existingDivs").css( {"bottom": ""} );
$(".existingDivs").css({"bottom":"90px"});
$(".existingDivs").animate({   
   top: '+= 92'          
},2000);
```

But it is not working in chrome and partially works in firefox.  Is there a way to append smooth sliding effect like  vertical ticker.

Answer (score 0):

This solution only uses jQuery and not css3 animations.

HTML:

`<div class="parent"></div>`

CSS:

```
.parent
{
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    text-align; center;
    position: relative;
}
.child
{
    width: 96px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 1px;
    position:absolute;
}
div
{
    border: 1px solid black;    
}
```

JS:

```
var child = $("<div></div>").addClass("child");
child.css("top","-44px");
$(".child").animate({"top": "+=44"});
$(".parent").prepend(child);
child.animate({"top":"0px"});
```

top += 44 because width of the child div is 40px and +4 to make up for the margin and the border.

Check the code out at:

http://jsfiddle.net/mSRg6/2/